# Check Structure for Entry or Child of Entry

Tags: entries, structure, navigation

I have setup a few different navigation lists through the Menus 0.9 plugin by Familiar. Within my website, I have setup several different site sections all through the same structure called, "General". They all share the same page template.

I would like to run a check to see if the page is "About" or is a child of "About" (all within the "General Structure"). If it is "About" or a child of "About", I would like to server it a specific sub-nav.

Here's the code to run that subnav:

```
{% nav node in craft.menus.getNodes('aboutSubnav') %}
<li><a href="{{node.link}}">{{ node.title }}</a></li>
{% endnav %}
```

How do I do the lookup to see what page it is? I tried the following code, but it did not work:

```
{% if entry in craft.entries.section('general').descendantOf(42) %}
 {% nav node in craft.menus.getNodes('aboutSubnav') %}
 <li><a href="{{node.link}}">{{ node.title }}</a></li>
 {% endnav %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The containment operator in does have problems working with whole element models. I'd try and modify your conditional to compare entry IDs instead:

```
{% if entry.id in craft.entries.section('general').descendantOf(42).ids() %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

To include that parent page ID to that array you would do that with the merge filter:

```
{% set aboutPagesIds = craft.entries.section('general').descendantOf(42).ids() %}
{% set aboutPagesIds = aboutPagesIds|merge([42]) %}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but is there a way to check for the parent as well as the descendant in the same if statement? It would include `{% if entry.id == 174 %}` and `{% if entry.id in craft.entries.section('general').descendantOf(42).ids() %}` together?

Comment: @jsilton I updated my answer. You could also combine the conditionals with `or`, but I like the above method better.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make some progress here. Below is the proper navigation aligned for the parent entries, but not the children.

```
{% if entry.id == 174 %}
 {% nav node in craft.menus.getNodes('ticketsSubnav') %}
 <li><a href="{{node.link}}">{{ node.title }}</a></li>
 {% endnav %}
{% endif %}

{% if entry.id == 53 %}
 {% nav node in craft.menus.getNodes('visitSubnav') %}
 <li><a href="{{node.link}}">{{ node.title }}</a></li>
 {% endnav %}
{% endif %}

{% if entry.id == 42 %}
 {% nav node in craft.menus.getNodes('aboutSubnav') %}
 <li><a href="{{node.link}}">{{ node.title }}</a></li>
 {% endnav %}
{% endif %}

{% if entry.id == 57 %}
 {% nav node in craft.menus.getNodes('supportSubnav') %}
 <li><a href="{{node.link}}">{{ node.title }}</a></li>
 {% endnav %}
{% endif %}
```

It's still not the answer yet, but closer.